# Caliburn.micro datagrid deleted button

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I am learning `Caliburn.Micro`. I am storing data from database into the DataGrid. I am able to access the data but not able to delete the data from DataGrid in CaliBurn.Micro. In my project I wants to have delete button in every row so that whenever i click the button of specific row then that row data will be deleted. I have tried but it is not working.

Here is my code

`ShellView.xaml`

```
 <Button x:Name="ButtonUpdate" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Update"/>
<DataGrid  x:Name="Empdata2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Empdata}" SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}" Height="162" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" First Name" Binding="{Binding Path= fname}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=lname}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="delete">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete"  x:Name="DeleteButton"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

`ShellViewModel.cs`

```
public class ShellViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    private string _firstname, _lastname;
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _empdata = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Empdata
    {
        get { return _empdata; }
        set
        {
            _empdata = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Empdata);
        }
    }

    Person model = new Person();

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstname; }
        set { _firstname = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set { _lastname = value; }
    }
    Auth obj = new Auth();
    public void ButtonUpdate()
    {
        DataSet d = new DataSet();
        d = obj.updateuser();

        for (int i = 0; i < d.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            Empdata.Add(new Person
            {
                fname = d.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                lname = d.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
            });
    }

    private Person _selecteditem;
    public Person selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => selecteditem);
        }
    }

    string sel;

    public void DeleteButton()
    {
        Auth obj = new Auth();
        sel = selecteditem.fname.ToString();
        bool find = obj.deluser(sel);
        if (find == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
        }
    }
}
```

`Person.cs`

```
public class Person:PropertyChangedBase
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    private string Firstname;
    public string fname
    {
        get { return Firstname; }
        set
        {
            Firstname = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => fname);
        }
    }
    private string Lastname;
    public string lname
    {
        get { return Lastname; }
        set
        {
            Lastname = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => lname);
        }
    }
}
```

`Auth.cs`

```
public class Auth
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = a; Initial Catalog = ab; Persist Security Info=True;User ID = s; Password=123");

    public DataSet updateuser()
    {
        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from [add]", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            return ds;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public bool deluser(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Delete from [add] where firstname=" + name + "", conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `cal:Bind.Model` attached property to your view model:

```
<DataTemplate xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <Button Content="Press Me" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            cal:Bind.Model="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
            x:Name="DeleteButton" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then the `DeleteButton` method of the `ShellViewModel` should be called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank You. Can you help one more problem whenever I click `add` my `textbox` should get empty, I have tried using `FirstName=string.Empty;` but it is only making the string value empty not the value showing in textbox . How can I do that

Comment: I have done it need to use `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);`

Comment: Now I need to add edit button to it. how can i do that?

Comment: @Ravi: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.